# CodeIgniter - ci_sessions migrations for website

Tags: php, mysql

Fixed the fatal error

Fatal error: Call to undefined function lang() in /home/u911295918/domains/engineer/public_html/apps/config/database.php on line 105

Now I am getting this error

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1146

Table 'u911295918_ealwebsite.ci_sessions' doesn't exist

INSERT INTO `ci_sessions` (`session_id`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`, `last_activity`, `user_data`) VALUES ('94f63864ee9e2cf2056f4d97c1bae747', '2405:201:c40b:109b:a12e:fece:1328:4e2', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36', 1703763835, '')

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 328

Resolution for the code